# Arcgis Visualbasic Templates

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, visual-studio

[image]I am using ArcGis 10 Template windows application(Desktop) in VisualStudio 2010. i have added an ArcGis Engine Map Control and engine TOC Control in that. when I am Adding my digitized map to the map control it is only showing my map not the digitized features and layers in map control. whereas in the TOC Control it is showing the name of all the layers. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the map to be the buddy control in the toc object: [SetBuddyControl](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/d/0016000003m2000000.htm)

Comment: did but its not helping :(

Comment: Then let us see some code, impossible to help you without seeing what you tried.

Comment: I really didnt do any coding. there was a video about developing .Net applications ESRI Summit 2012. in which they have told about the map control application. I followed the same procedure. but I am having this problem. here is the link of the video " http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1366/ds2010-developing-net-applications-for-arcgis-engine " i am also adding the snapshot of my application.